# Ошибка "got an unexpected keyword argument" при создании суперпользователя в django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Переопределил модель User для авторизации по email:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = None
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    #поля учетной записи
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, verbose_name="email")
    phone = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=11, verbose_name="phone")
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        'active',
        default=True,
        help_text='Designates whether this user should be treated as active.',
    )
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField('date joined', default=timezone.now)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField('last login')
       
    objects = UserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    EMAIL_FIELD = "email"
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        if self.company_name:
            return self.company_name
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        if self.company_name:
            return self.company_name
        return self.email
  
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None, **kwargs):
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email], **kwargs)    

    @property
    def is_superuser(self):
        return self.is_superuser

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            _alg = identify_hasher(self.password)
        except ValueError:
            self.password = make_password(self.password)
        # if not self.id and not self.staff and not self.admin:
        #     self.password = make_password(self.password)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a user with the given username, email, and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Пользователь должен иметь и-мэйл адрес')
        if not password:
            raise ValueError('Пользователь должен ввести пароль')

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields):        
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields):        
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def with_perm(self, perm, is_active=True, include_superusers=True, backend=None, obj=None):
        if backend is None:
            backends = auth._get_backends(return_tuples=True)
            if len(backends) == 1:
                backend, _ = backends[0]
            else:
                raise ValueError(
                    'You have multiple authentication backends configured and '
                    'therefore must provide the `backend` argument.'
                )
        elif not isinstance(backend, str):
            raise TypeError(
                'backend must be a dotted import path string (got %r).'
                % backend
            )
        else:
            backend = auth.load_backend(backend)
        if hasattr(backend, 'with_perm'):
            return backend.with_perm(
                perm,
                is_active=is_active,
                include_superusers=include_superusers,
                obj=obj,
            )
        return self.none()


    # A few helper functions for common logic between User and AnonymousUser.
    def _user_get_permissions(user, obj, from_name):
            permissions = set()
            name = 'get_%s_permissions' % from_name
            for backend in auth.get_backends():
                if hasattr(backend, name):
                    permissions.update(getattr(backend, name)(user, obj))
            return permissions


    def _user_has_perm(user, perm, obj):
            """
            A backend can raise `PermissionDenied` to short-circuit permission checking.
            """
            for backend in auth.get_backends():
                if not hasattr(backend, 'has_perm'):
                    continue
                try:
                    if backend.has_perm(user, perm, obj):
                        return True
                except PermissionDenied:
                    return False
            return False


    def _user_has_module_perms(user, app_label):
        """
        A backend can raise `PermissionDenied` to short-circuit permission checking.
        """
        for backend in auth.get_backends():
            if not hasattr(backend, 'has_module_perms'):
                continue
            try:
                if backend.has_module_perms(user, app_label):
                    return True
            except PermissionDenied:
                return False
        return False
```

При создании суперпользователя python manage.py createsuperuser

возникает ошибка - **TypeError: User() got an unexpected keyword argument 'is_superuser'**

```
на строке  user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields) 
из def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields),
class UserManager(BaseUserManager)
```

отладчиком проверяю extra_fields, is_superuser=true

Подскажите новичку в какую сторону копать, спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо убрать `**` отсюда `**is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)**`

UPD.
Ок, тогда проблема в том, что у вас `is_superuser` является и полем БД и свойством (property), поэтому возникает проблема, необходимо одно из двух переименовать.
Вижу еще одну проблему, которая не даст создать суперпользователя через manage.py, это `last_login` там необходимо добавить `null=True`

Comment: в коде нет **, в данном блоке is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False), я хотел выделить разметкой этот участок при публикации вопроса

Comment: Спасибо! Убрал свойство `is_superuser` в `User` и добавил `null=True` для `last_login`, все заработало.